# string defined but unresolved?

Tags: java, android, string, resources

I have strings defined in my strings.xml as:

```
<resources>
<string name="edit_student">Edit Student</string>
<string name="add_activity">Add Activity</string>
<string name="act_name">Activity</string>
</resources>
```

But when I reference it with ..

```
setTitle(R.string.add_activity);
```

..it fails with error.

```
add_activity cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

However a similar statement in another place works just fine

```
setTitle(R.string.edit_student);
```

What's wrong with the first one that doesn't but the second does?

Comment: Make sure you didn't import android.R in the first file.

Comment: The [tag:r] tag refers to R the statistical processing language.  I have removed it from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from verifying your imports (for the R class), try doing a clean build. Sometimes the R class is not regenerated correct

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the string resources directly. Use it as following:

```
setTitle(context.getString(R.string.resource_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the import statements of your class file, from which package R is imported.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.add_activity));
```

Comment: Just doing a clean build did.it.